# Nodemailing using variables to send an email with a Javascript Discord bot

Tags: javascript, discord

I'm trying to make a Discord bot email certain people based on information using Nodemailer. I am using variables to choose who to send emails to. Whenever I try to use it, it fails to send the email and says the variables are undefined. Here is my code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
        user: 'user',
        pass: 'pass'
    }
});
var mailOptions = {
  from: 'someemail@gmail.com',
  to: firstname + "." + lastname + "@gmail.com",
  subject: 'Sending Email using Node.js',
  text: 'That was easy!'
};    
var firstname = "";
var lastname = "";
var chat = 0;
var placeholder = "";
client.on("message", message => {
    var prefix = '!';
if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + "chat") && chat == 0) {
    chat = chat + 1;
    message.channel.send("Welcome! I am Sabrina, a friendly chatbot. By the way, what is your first name?");    
} else if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + "chat") && chat == 1) {
    chat = chat + 1;
    placeholder = message.content;
    firstname = placeholder.replace("!chat ", "");
    message.channel.send("Very intresting name, " + firstname + ". 
    What is your last name?");
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
    }
}   
});
}
}); 
client.login("Token")
```

Comment: Firstly, fix the multiline string you've got here: `message.channel.send("Very intresting name, " + firstname + .....` - this fails for me.  Use backticks (or the `\n` character) to write strings over multiple lines.

Answer (score 1):

```
var mailOptions = {
  from: 'someemail@gmail.com',
  to: firstname + "." + lastname + "@gmail.com",
  subject: 'Sending Email using Node.js',
  text: 'That was easy!'
};
```

This part is evaluated at the time it's parsed - before the rest of the code runs, so before `firstname` and `lastname` are filled (or even initialized as `""`). It's not dynamically updated as those variables change.

Since you want to, essentially, construct `mailOptions` dynamically, why not make a function that does it?

```
// Traditional syntax
function getMailOptions(first, last) {
  return {
    from: 'someemail@gmail.com',
    to: first + "." + last + "@gmail.com",
    subject: 'Sending Email using Node.js',
    text: 'That was easy!'
  }
}

// Or, since you're using arrow functions..
const getMailOptions = (first, last) => ({
  from: 'someemail@gmail.com',
  to: first + "." + last + "@gmail.com",
  subject: 'Sending Email using Node.js',
  text: 'That was easy!'
});
```

Now you can use it:

```
transporter.sendMail(getMailOptions(firstname, lastname), function(error, info){
  /* ... */
```